# change uibarbuttonitem background using image

Tags: image, ipad, background, uibarbuttonitem

i have an uibarbuttonitem, but i was initialize it using initwithcustomview. I want to change it backgrounds using an image, but i dont know how to do. I was using setBackground method, like this

```
NSArray *segmentText = [segmentTextMutable copy];
UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] init] autorelease];
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bunga.jpg"];
_docSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentText];
_docSegmentedControl.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
_docSegmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled;
[_docSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(docSegmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[_docSegmentedControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image]];
```

but the uibarbuttonitem still not show the image, it's just change the segmented control background, not the barbutton.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to change the tint-color (@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *tintColor) because UISegmentedControl has no background-color (just because it inherits it from UIView does not mean it uses it though)

Comment: can i fill tintColor with an image?